# How to build a Keycloak custom docker image with disabled ssl for AWS?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to build a custom docker image(new to docker) where SSL is disabled by default for AWS environment as we know  Keycloak admin console allows only https by default for all external IP addresses.

I am aware of the below code snippet that disables it manually.

`docker exec -it {contaierID} bash cd /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin ./kcadm.sh update  realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE`

I basically want to automate these above command in my custom keycloak docker image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to connect to admin console after I passed below configuration as environmental parameter to the docker image. KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://host/auth

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't do that. HTTPS is required for OIDC protocol. The secure option is to configure proper HTTPS setup, for example AWS ALB with correct TLS certificate and standard `jboss/keycloak` Docker image (running on EC2, ECS, EKS, Fargate, ...) with `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`. See https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: Hi @Jan Garaj, thanks for your response. now i am kecloak behind ALB. but getting the below error while accessing admin console. please note that my port number is 8080.

Comment: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://<keycloakhost>/auth/admin/master/console/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://<keycloakhost>/auth/js/keycloak.js?version=x7bkk'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Keycloak is not defined ReferenceError: Keycloak is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://<keycloakhost>/auth/resources/x7bkk/admin/keycloak/js/app.js:14:24)`

Comment: `    at e (https://<keycloakhost>/auth/resources/x7bkk/common/keycloak/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://<keycloakhost>/auth/resources/x7bkk/common/keycloak/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined
S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Keycloak is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:14)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: Finally I was able to connect to admin console after I passed below configuration as environmental parameter to the docker image.
`KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://host/auth`